How to turn decimal to byte array but it has to be lexicographically sortable?
As for double BitConverter.GetBytes(double) reversed returns array that if lexicographically sorted will be sorted the same as (positive) doubles. Can the same be done for decimal?
For example:
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((double)input);
Array.Reverse(bytes);
PrintBytes(bytes);

Input = 2 bytes are:
64 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

Input = 2.05
64 0 102 102 102 102 102 102 

Input = 2.1
64 0 204 204 204 204 204 205 


If you assume the decimal is "normalised" (does not have trailing zeros), then GetBits almost returns what you want. If you need to distinguish between e.g. 1m and 1.0m though, working out a binary encoding with this property would be very hard.

decimal can have normalised and non-normalised values. In other words, it contains a 96-bit Significand in the lower bits, and an 8-bit Scale (power of 10) in some of the high bits, as well as the top bit containing the Sign. So how would you sort 1 * 10 ^ 2 and 101 * 10 ^ 1 ? It's not clear how you want to do that. For that matter, what do you mean by "lexicographically"? What do you for negatives, what do you do for the scale etc etc?

@Charlieface Comparing two arrays lexicographically means zipping the two arrays and compare the first pair of elements that are unequal. If all elements are equal, then the two arrays are equal. If I understand correctly, OP is trying to find a binary encoding of decimal such that comparing the byte[]s produced by the binary encoding produces the same result as comparing the decimals. This is a property that holds true for doubles that are non-negative, non-NaN, non-infinity.

@Sweeper My point is that it doesn't really make sense on Two's Complement numbering anyway (negatives go upwards not downwards), especially with the Scale involved like I said.

I think OP is aware of that since they said "will be sorted the same as (positive) doubles", so I think they don't care about negative numbers. And yes, I'm hoping for a clarification on how scales are expected to be dealt with, too.

I just wanted to deal with the positive numbers first. So I see now that decimals are complicated, I was hoping for an easy solution. Will have to dig deeper I guess...

The obvious answer would be to convert the decimal to a double and then leverage the behavior that you already acknowledged as acceptable for your purpose.
e.g. BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToDouble(input))

Update
You are correct in stating that conversion from a decimal to a double loses precision.  So, if the comparisons you are making actually depend upon the precision level of the decimal type then my suggestion above would not be acceptable.  However, it's worth noting that the comments from the Decimal type definition state that

A conversion from Decimal to float or double may lose precision, but will not lose information about the overall magnitude of the numeric value, and will never throw an exception.

I could imagine cases where rounding the precision would be acceptable so long as the rounded magnitude was consistent, but I can also imagine cases where it might not be acceptable.  Assuming that it isn't, it should be possible to get a byte representation like what you initially requested, although it will not be quite as straightforward as for a double.
All the BitConverter.GetBytes(double) does is copy the underlying binary data from the double value.  You can do this with a decimal but the results will be a bit different.  But, you should be able to convert the bytes into a representation that is acceptable to you if you are clear about what it is you are attempting to compare.  Again, decimals are a little more complex than doubles, as you must contend with the sign, the scale factor and the choice of how to interpret redundant representations of equivalent values.

The lo, mid, hi, and flags fields contain the representation of the Decimal value. The lo, mid, and hi fields contain the 96-bit integer part of the Decimal. Bits 0-15 (the lower word) of the flags field are unused and must be zero; bits 16-23 contain must contain a value between 0 and 28, indicating the power of 10 to divide the 96-bit integer part by to produce the Decimal value; bits 24-30 are unused and must be zero; and finally bit 31 indicates the sign of the Decimal value, 0 meaning positive and 1 meaning negative.

There are a few places you should look to understand how the decimal is formatted and sorted:

The Decimal constructor shows how the decimal type is built from four 32-bit binary number inputs.  I found the comments in the source code here to be quite helpful.


Constructs a Decimal from an integer array containing a binary representation. The bits argument must be a non-null integer array with four elements. bits[0], bits[1], and bits[2] contain the low, middle, and high 32 bits of the 96-bit integer part of the Decimal. bits[3] contains the scale factor and sign of the Decimal: bits 0-15 (the lower word) are unused and must be zero; bits 16-23 must contain a value between 0 and 28, indicating the power of 10 to divide the 96-bit integer part by to produce the Decimal value; bits 24-30 are unused and must be zero; and finally bit 31 indicates the sign of the Decimal value, 0 meaning positive and 1 meaning negative.
Note that there are several possible binary representations for the same numeric value. For example, the value 1 can be represented as {1, 0, 0, 0} (integer value 1 with a scale factor of 0) and equally well as {1000, 0, 0, 0x30000} (integer value 1000 with a scale factor of 3). The possible binary representations of a particular value are all equally valid, and all are numerically equivalent.


Decimal.GetBits(decimal) is the operation that you will use to extract the underlying binary representation from the decimal value in the same way as you used BitConverter.GetBytes(double) in your question.  However, you'll get an array of 4 32-bit integers instead of an array of 8 8-bit integers.


Returns a binary representation of a Decimal. The return value is an integer array with four elements. Elements 0, 1, and 2 contain the low, middle, and high 32 bits of the 96-bit integer part of the Decimal. Element 3 contains the scale factor and sign of the Decimal: bits 0-15 (the lower word) are unused; bits 16-23 contain a value between 0 and 28, indicating the power of 10 to divide the 96-bit integer part by to produce the Decimal value; bits 24-30 are unused; and finally bit 31 indicates the sign of the Decimal value, 0 meaning positive and 1 meaning negative.


Decimal.DecCalc.VarDecCmp and Decimal.DecCalc.VarDecCmpSub contain the logic for comparing two decimal values.  The comparison is more nuanced than just a lexicographical sort.  Your intentions for handling scale and sign of the decimal were not clear from the question, but if you know what you want to do here you should be able to work out a solution.
Both scale and sign come from the _flags int in the decimal, and there are a couple constant fields that you'll need to make sense of them: SignMask; and, ScaleMask


yes, but the precision is lost

@ren then maybe pick a fixed precision factor, and convert the numbers to integers - for example, if you want to use 0.001 as the precision, you'd store the decimal 1.520 as the integer 1520. Not perfect, but it is sortable, doesn't use floating point logic, and is very fast

yes, actualy working on something like that. That same logic can be applied to fractional part too. With enough bytes maybe the full decimal precision can be supported

@ren you're in Int128 territory for that, but in most real-world scenarios 32 or 64 bit is enough to work well

decimal.TryGetBits on a stackalloc span might be more efficient.

I thought the answer was likely yes, but @Charlieface in comments pointed out that a Decimal can be denormalized, which seems like it would destroy the sort order.
Original answer contains some info about the format.

Maybe. It seems like they'd want to make it easy to compare.
Documentation for Decimal.GetBits describes the internal format.
The way I read that doc, Decimal is a 128-bit value, laid out in four 32-bit signed integers:
0 - low 32 bits of the value
1 - middle 32 bits of the value
2 - high 32 bits of the value
3 - flags

In the flags value, the high bit is the sign bit and bits 16 to 23 contain the exponent. All other bits in flags are required to be zero.
Looks to me like if you compare in the order [3,2,1,0], then you'll get a proper comparison.
Here are the outputs from Decimal.GetBits(), for 2 and -2:
Decimal.GetBits(2)
  0: 00000002
  1: 00000000
  2: 00000000
  3: 00000000
Decimal.GetBits(-2)
  0: 00000002
  1: 00000000
  2: 00000000
  3: 80000000

The sign bit is indeed in the last dword, and the low bits are definitely in the first dword.
So I'd say that they are lexicographically sortable, although your sorting application will have to know how to load and compare 128-bit numbers.

This is incorrect: a decimal can be denormalised, for example 1 * 10 ^ 2 instead of 100 * 10 ^ 0, so these would sort differently even if identical, etc

@Charlieface Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer.
